# how to define this $ react JS

Tags: reactjs, carousel, owl-carousel

I have created app using create-react-app. I import owl.carousel but why it is showing this error.

how to define this $

```
  Line 12:15:  '$' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 21:5:   '$' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 24:5:   '$' is not defined  no-undef
```

**Here is the Component Code**

```
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
    owl.owlCarousel({
      items: 4,
      loop: true,
      margin: 10,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplayTimeout: 1000,
      autoplayHoverPause: true,
    });
    $(".play").on("click", function () {
      owl.trigger("play.owl.autoplay", [1000]);
    });
    $(".stop").on("click", function () {
      owl.trigger("stop.owl.autoplay");
    });
```

**Cannot read property of undefined.**
[this picture of error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9JOS.png)

Comment: Have you searched for [jquery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Not answering the question, but it cannot be a good idea to combine jquery with react. It is better to use react refs => https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @lanxion OP isn't the one combining it, but rather the `owl` module they're using is, and jquery appears to be a peer dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import jQuery to your project with ReactJS like so...

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Before you can do that, you must install it to your project.  See the NPM documentation for more info: [npm->jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery).  You can install it with npm by means of...

```
npm install --save jquery
```

And you can know the installation worked by checking your `package.json` file and seeing...

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  ....
```

Comment: Also, according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel, you are required to do some webpack config to inject a global window.jquery